# Laravel - Set Select2 Default to NULL rather than First Option

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-select2

I have a Laravel edit form that utilizes the Select2 jQuery extension with options pulled from a database table.

Below is the form select field I am referring to:

```
            <select id="ship_to" name="ship_to" class="js-example-basic-single2 form-control">
                @foreach($cCustomers as $customer)
                    <option value="{{$customer->id}}"
                    @if ($shipment->ship_to == $customer->id) selected="selected" 
                                 @endif
                    >{{$customer->customer_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

Now, everything pops up fine, the options are there, the select box has been transformed into a Select2 format. My problem is that when I pull data from a database, if the specific column is empty, the select2 pulls the first option, rather than the allowed null choice (and yes I have selected a placeholder), clearing the select2 box works just fine.

So my question goes as such:

If I have a record where the select's field is NULL, how do I get the page to open up automatically will the null value and placeholder in my select2 box, rather than the first option?

Current Output:

```
<select id="ship_to" name="ship_to" class="js-example-basic-single2 form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="ship_to" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <option></option>
        <option value="164" data-select2-id="387">4G ENTERPRISES</option>
        <option value="192">4G ENTERPRISES</option>
        <option value="81">5280 PACKAGING</option>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://select2.org/placeholders). Make sure that on your select2 options, you set a placeholder:

```
$('#ship_to').select2({
    placeholder: "Please select a customer"
});
```

And add an empty option in the `<select>` (Just above the `@foreach($cCustomers as $customer)`:

```
<option></option>
```

Comment: Yes, as I said in my question I have added a placeholder, and I have added your suggestion but as before it is still the first @foreach option that gets the data-select2-id flag to it and is select, not the empty option.

Comment: @Matthew Check the actual outputted code, and see if you see `selected="selected"` anywhere. If you've added an empty placeholder at the top, the first option to be selected should be that first option.

Comment: See my updated question. At the button is the current output, that is exactly that it looks like and the remaining <options> are all the same format as option value 192 and 81.

Comment: Just add an if statement before the foreach loop that adds another option (That is selected), if ship_to is null.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an option with null value before foreach.

```
<option value=""></option>
```

Add above line before foreach

Comment: How about using form collective?